# NLTK tell if word is generated by CFG

Tags: nltk, context-free-grammar, context-free-language, cyk, earley-parser

Given string and a context-free grammar I need to tell if the grammar generates the string or not using NLTK

I tried using some opensource solution from github but it doesnt work correctly with this example:

> S ->
> S -> B A10 | B0
> A1 -> T A2
> A10 -> T A20 | T0
> A2 -> c
> A20 -> c |
> T -> b
> T0 -> b |
> T -> C T
> T0 -> C T0 | C0
> B -> a
> B0 -> a
> B0 ->
> S0 -> B A1
> C -> b
> C0 -> b |

and string a b b b c, which is in the CFL but the solution says its not

Answer (score 0):

You can just use RecursiveDescentParser from https://www.nltk.org/howto/parse.html
and iterate over parser.parse(word), if you iterate more than 0 times - word is in the language.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).